# Mini Cart does not update Cookie issue - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, cart

I've got to work on [this site](http://anchor-electronics.com/) which is running Flatsome theme. i've updated both woocommerce and flatsome to it's newest versions. (woocommerce 2.5 and flatsome Version: 2.8.1)
and the site works perfectly, except for the mini cart. when an item is added it registers in the mini cart. but thereafter any addition or removal of items are not shown in the mini cart. in layman's terms it freezes! even when the cart is cleared it will show the same initial product(s) added.

Tried disabling all plugins including W3C total cache and still no luck?

Can someone please help me? Pretty please?

PS - If you reload the site while this issue is happening, you can see for a brief moment the actual cart value is there in the mini cart, but it resets back to a wrong value when the site is fully loaded. i believe this is caused by a cookie issue but i don't know where to start .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was Server caching! Disabled varnish and we're golden.

Hope this help any other facing the same issue as i am. [Go to the Wordpress thread here for Mike's Awesome Solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mini-cart-does-not-update-after-woocommerce-25-update?replies=3#post-7946281)

Thank you everyone who take a look into this! :)

Answer (score -1):

Huh... Luckily i recently worked in the exact teplate for the production of an e-shop. The point is that Flatsome has a mechanism where the DOM is replaced with AJAX after the initial load. So I recommend the use of firebug to see which javascript files are running on load. 
In my experience the problem was with a global php file under woocommerce plugin. Also the developers of this template have put comments in the code in case someone needs to change something in their site.

To sum up, you should not alter the core files of Woocommerce because it gets messy when the AJAX replacements take place. I recommend you replace the whole woocommerce plugin with a fresh one in a new installation and see how it works.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Yes did exactly the same! removed the old woocommerce directory and uploaded the newest (2.5v) woocommerce and checked! still getting the same thing. i've written to woocommerce support as well. i'm not sure what to do man. :/

Comment: And the problem occurs even when the theme is changed! So when reported to the theme devs, they suggests the same thing of replacing woocommerce which is not working.

Comment: Well this is actually pretty wierd. You should check the names of the classes and ids that are in the mini-cart.php file under Flatsome.

Then compare them with the class names that show up after the AJAX replacements.

Comment: flatsome do not have a mini-cart.php override for Woocommerce? will it work if i creat a one?